# rails routing show action nested resources

Tags: ruby-on-rails, resources, controller, routes, nested

Yeah the problem is, that I created a nested resource like this:

```
resources :albums do 
  resources :elements
end
```

and the rake routes command displays:

```
album_element GET /albums/:album_id/elements/:id(.:format) elements#show
```

So when I am at 
.../albums/1
I can head for
.../albums/1/elements

This starts the index action of the elements controller, just fine.
But if I edit the index.html.erb to

```
<%= link_to 'Show', album_element_path %>
```

I got an error like this:

```
Started GET "/albums/1/elements" for 176.221.47.67 at Tue Oct 09 14:25:39 +0200 2012
Processing by ElementsController#index as HTML
Parameters: {"album_id"=>"1"}
Rendered elements/index.html.erb within layouts/application (9.2ms)
Completed 500 Internal Server Error in 123ms

ActionController::RoutingError (No route matches {:controller=>"elements", :action=>"show"}):
app/views/elements/index.html.erb:29:in `_app_views_elements_index_html_erb___13604879__168097178'
app/views/elements/index.html.erb:18:in `each'
app/views/elements/index.html.erb:18:in `_app_views_elements_index_html_erb___13604879__168097178'
app/controllers/elements_controller.rb:7:in `index'
```

So it says that no route matches ... but I actually have that in my rake routes displayed ?
What am I doing wrong ?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You need to provide the two neccesary arguments for album_element_path:

```
<%= link_to 'Show', album_element_path(@album, @element) %>
```

Comment: Thanks for the quick answer but I get another error then.
Probalby I need to set @albums ? but where ?
I changed it to 
<%= link_to 'Show', album_element_path(@album, @element) %>
And added in the show method of the element controller:
@album= Album.find(params[:album_id])

Comment: If anyone is interested in the solution, it is:
<%= link_to 'Show', album_element_path(@album, element) %>

Because I was in a for each - and had to use element instead of @element.

Comment: @element probably needs to be replaced by the iterator you use in index.html.erb

Comment: Hm now I added
<%= link_to 'Edit', edit_album_element_path(@album, element) %>

But when I click on it, I get: 
ActionView::Template::Error (undefined method `element_path' for #<#<Class:0xebde8fa0>:0xebde59f4>):
    1: <%= form_for(@element) do |f| %>
Do I have to fix this @element somehow ?